# Table not showing output in new line

Tags: powershell, format

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I'm stuck.  The output in the members column is like this

> {domain\Domain Admins, domain\joerod...

How can I show the

> $member

value on each line?

```
Function Get-AdminGroups{

foreach($i in (Get-Content C:\Users\joerod\Desktop\remove_users.txt)){

#test if machine is on the network
if (-not (Test-Connection -computername $i -count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Warning "$i is Unavalible"
        "`r"
        }
 else {
(invoke-command {
$members = net localgroup administrators | 
 ? {$_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | 
 select -skip 4
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
 Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
 Users=$members
 }
} -computer $i -HideComputerName | 
Select * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID )
  }
}
 }
Get-AdminGroups |ft
```

Comment: Try FL instead of FT.

Comment: the does show all the groups but I want it in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through $members and make an object for each one. This creates an empty array, loops through the computers in your text file, and in that loop it pulls a list of the local administrators, and for each one it creates a custom object just like you are doing, and it adds it to that array.

```
$Results = @()
foreach($i in (GC C:\Users\joerod\Desktop\remove_users.txt)){
    #test if machine is on the network
    if (!(Test-Connection -computername $i -count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Warning "$i is Unavalible`r"
        Continue
    }
    invoke-command {
        $members = net localgroup administrators |?{$_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | select -skip 4
        ForEach($member in $members){
            $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Users=$member
            }
        }
    } -computer $i -HideComputerName # | Select * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID
}
$Results | FT
```

Comment: Im getting an error when running this script.  Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: Sorry, move $results = @() to after $members = and before ForEach